# How to make ProfileViews count in laravel?

Tags: laravel-8

I need help. How do I create profile visitors in **Laravel 8**? I have not written the code yet and I do not even have an idea how to complete this task. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the visitor without any profile. He will be able to access public web pages without authentication and therefore only logged in users will have profile.

## UPDATE

### Proposed skeleton in two steps using cookies

1- When a user make request on profile page generate an unique identifier and store it in user cookie with a long enough validity if it not yet exists

2- Using this unique token register a new view count (if not yet done) before sending response to user.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

public function getProfilePage(Request $request){

  if(!Cookie::has('uniqueId')){
    $uniqueId  = Str::uuid(); // generate unique id for current user
    Cookie::queue('uniqueId', $uniqueId, [live time in minutes]); 
    // save it using Cookie::queue
    // one year for example as live time
  }
  // check if view count already exists for $uniqueId
  // and save it in a persistent way if not
  
  // other stuff ....
  
  return ....
}
```

Comment: My website is social network, and i need to count user profile views.

Comment: you can assign a unique identifier to the users that you store in cookie with a long enough period of validity and use this for the count of views

Comment: Can you help me write the code? I do not know where and how to add :(

Comment: Skeleton proposal added in the original answer

Comment: Thank you my friend <3